# Prevent sed from outputting rest of file

Tags: macos, bash, sed

I am using `sed` to extract something between 2 strings in a file. I am using:

```
sed 's/^.*bbb //; s/ddd.*$//' '/Users/myName/Desktop/sedtest.txt'
```

and the file contains:

```
aaa bbb ccc ddd eee
more random text
…
```

when I use the above sed command it successfully extracts `ccc` but it also outputs the lines below. It outputs:

```
ccc
more random text
…
```

but i only want it to output:

```
ccc
```

How do I modify the command so that it only outputs `ccc`? Furthermore, I will not know at runtime that `ccc` is what is between `bbb` and `ddd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
grep bbb yourfile | grep ddd | sed yourcommand
```

That will only operate on lines containing "bbb" and "ddd".

Answer (score 1):

No need to chain greps when sed can do it just as easily itself.

```
sed 's/^.*bbb\(.*\)ddd.*$/\1/;t a;d;:a' /Users/myName/Desktop/sedtest.txt
```

Comment: "Just as easily" he said, using arcane and "poorly documented" sed commands (http://www.grymoire.com/unix/sed.html). Everybody can read "grep a | grep b" as... find only lines containing "a" and "b" :-)

Comment: I get `sed: 1: "s/^.*bbb\(.*\)ddd.*$/\1 ...": undefined label 'a;d;:a'` when running this command

Comment: @AdamJohns try putting a space after the first a, before the semicolon.

Comment: `just as easily`...really ?

Comment: Am I really the only one who knows more than the `s` sed command?

Comment: @Kevin `sed: 1: "s/^.*bbb\(.*\)ddd.*$/\1 ...": undefined label 'a ;d;:a'`

Comment: Interesting, what version of sed? Try taking out the a, just `...;t;d`

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk '/bbb.*ddd/ {gsub(/.*bbb | ddd.*/,x);print}' file
ccc
```

It selects line only with `bbb` and `ddd`. Then remove all up to `bbb` and from `ddd`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/^.*bbb\(.*\)ddd.*$/|\1|/' /tmp/file.txt | grep '^|' | cut -d\| -f2
```